MP4 file created using MediaRecorder API is not playable
I am trying to generate an mp4 file from a screen recording done via a chrome extension. The video plays back perfectly on the browser, but when I download the file and play it back locally with a media player it says that the file seems to be corrupted or the codec isn't supported. This is how I am creating the media file -
const options = {mimeType: 'video/mp4'};
var combined_stream = this.CreateCombinedStream();
this.media_recorder_ = new MediaRecorder(combined_stream, options);

CreateCombinedStream function creates a final video file that adds audio as well to the video stream if required based on an input. This is how it is implemented
VideoRecorder.prototype.CreateCombinedStream = function () {
    var combined_stream = null;
    if (this.need_audio_ && this.audio_tracks_.length) {
        var audioContext = new AudioContext();
        var dest = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.audio_tracks_.length; i++) {
            var audio = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(new MediaStream([this.audio_tracks_[i]]));
            audio.connect(dest);
        }
        combined_stream = new MediaStream([this.screen_track_, dest.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]]);
    } else {
        combined_stream = new MediaStream([this.screen_track_]);
    }
    return combined_stream;
}

In the stop event listener of the media recorder, the final blob is created as follows -
var blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "video/mp4" });

This blob is now passed to a video element
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob) + '#t=0.5';

Things tried:

Initially I thought it was something to do with the codecs, so I tried specifying different codecs as mentioned here AVC Codecs but the video still doesn't play

FFprobe output -


Sounds like a bug in the player or in Chrome, assuming you used the native download option in the video menu.

Yes, I used the native download option in the video controls. However I couldn't find anything reported for it

Which player you are using

@Christoph, I'm using the default windows media player. Tried it on a mac and quicktime doesn't play it either. Can playback the videos on VLC though

OK i was sure VLC can gg. What does VLC Shows in the codec info? Also show maybe the output of ffprobe

My tipp is that the issue is the codec

@Christoph: Yeah seems like it, when I specify no codecs at all and just video/mp4, it picks up the default VP9 codec. This plays back in VLC with no problems. However, when I change the codec to AVC using the Constrained Base Profile (video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"), VLC is unable to play back the video. I have modified the description and attached the ffprobe output

Seems like this is a bug, I think its the same issue that I'm facing as well. Check this out - https://issues.chromium.org/issues/348923066

Sounds correct to me using h264 confirm your setup with Chrome Canary 128.0.6602.2 to check if you run Into this issue

Yep, works well in the canary build. @Christoph thanks for all the support!

Cool  you are Welcome
